# rmod iwlagn error message (it is not loaded)?

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to fix my slow wifi connection and when I typed 
the command I got an error message.

```
rmmod iwlagn:
rmmod: ERROR: Module iwlagn is not currently loaded
```

Comment: So... Why do you expect that iwlagn modules is loaded?. Are you following some tutorial?.  What are your trying to achieve?.

Comment: hello, i am trying to fix the sudden slow wifi connection on ubuntu14.04 and was following one of the answers.

Comment: Which answer?. Do you have the same hardware?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/606108/wireless-internet-connection-suddenly-slows-down-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: i do have the same hardware. i was following the comments in that question.

Comment: I still don't understand what are you looking for or what are you expecting. Sorry but you should probably rework the question if you want to obtain help.

Comment: Are you following [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395)?  If not, you should try that one first!

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. rmmod is trying to remove a module that is not loaded.